# Keep new line, when the HTML is on 1 line and new line layout is done with <div>

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I need to get content from a site

I need to get

```
/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/form/fieldset[2]/table[2]
```

or

```
<table class='properties'>
```

For which the code is visible here: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/347881/

contents with all the content formatted just on new lines.
I don't care about paddings, and other formatting, I just want to keep the new lines.

For example a proper output would be

```
tájékoztató
az eljárás eredményéről
A Közbeszerzések Tanácsa (Szerkesztőbizottsága) tölti ki
A hirdetmény kézhezvételének dátuma____________________
KÉ nyilvántartási szám_________________________________
I. SZAKASZ: AJÁNLATKÉRŐ
I.1) Név, cím és kapcsolattartási pont(ok)
```

The problem I face that the new lines are introduced with the div's and cannot get it.

**Update**

This be executed by a PHP cron, so there is no access to JS.

Comment: can't you just build the result by iterating through the divs? what code have you tried so far? What are you using to parse the html?

Comment: Iterating through divs could cause a problem sometimes, because there can be multiple levels nested, and content is displayed on the same line on the real layout. I've just tried replacing divs with br-s but results in too many new lines. I am using regexp to get the table source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a library called `phpQuery`: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

You can walk through DOM object like with `jQuery`:

```
phpQuery::newDocument($htmlCode)->find('table.properties');
```

On a mached element's content fire `strip_tags` and you will get pure content of that table.

Comment: Sorry, I need to use only by PHP, it will be executed by a cron script only, no access to JS.

Comment: @Pentium10: check it again, phpQuery is php code, not JS - just resembles jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to fetch the inner divs in an xpath expression, then use their textContent property:

```
<?php

$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML(file_get_contents("..."));
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
$items = $domx->query("/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tr/td/div/div[2]/form/fieldset[2]/table[2]/tr/td/div//div/div[@style='padding-left: 0px;']");

$output = "";
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $output .= $item->textContent . "\n";
}

echo $output;
```